# Is there a tool like JQAssistant for Typescript

Tags: typescript, dependency-management, code-analysis, jqassistant

I'm currently working on code analysis and using this tool https://jqassistant.org/ to query the code of a Java application, I'm able right now to query all the feign clients and relationships between a set of jar files what gives me a dependency matrix based on the code, is really cool. But I don't know if you know a similar tool that does the same process based on a TypeScript code, particularly on an Angular 8+ application, we have a lot of micro-apps(backend and frontend) and I'm interested in build a code-based dependency matrix.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there's no Typescript support for jQAssistant yet, but scanner prototypes are currently work in progress.

Comment: Is there any progress on the Typescript parsers? Is it possible at all (since TS is heavily moving)?

Comment: There is actually progress, see the answer below. Feedback is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

As of a few weeks ago there actually exists a TypeScript plugin for jQAssistant.

You can find more information about it on GitHub: https://github.com/jqassistant-plugin/jqassistant-typescript-plugin